Cannot Access Contentful Space on Environment "Master" with access token
On my local machine, when I go to run npm start, I received an error:

"Cannot access Contentful space "" on environment "master"
with access token "*********" Make sure to double check
them!"

I double checked, they are all good! I also recreated new ones to try again and I am still getting the same error. I am able to use these same env variables on Netlify and it deploys... so I am confused as to why it does not work on my local machine.
Does anyone know any steps towards a solution?

i think you need to give us the code, what is suddenly ? the context is not enough to understand

@Zulzidan.com I am unsure what part of my code to give you other than my env file. Netlify deploys the site so I know that the env variables are correct. However, on my local machine, it says they are not.

have you read this ? https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/22211

Where did you get the access token? Sounds like you are using a management token instead of a delivery token. Think of it as write token vs read token. Make sure you are using the correct one.
